# Reduce an Array of object based on value of attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, filter

I am trying to create a new array of object from an existing array of object based on the common attribute (category.blocktitle) value inside the object. My array of object looks like this.

```
[
  {
    "category": {
      "name": "test1111",
      "val": "test111111111",
      "blocktitle": ".test.0"
    }
  },
  {
    "category": {
      "name": "test22",
      "val": "test2222",
      "blocktitle": ".test.0.test2"
    }
  },
  {
    "category": {
      "name": "test1111111",
      "val": "test11111111111",
      "blocktitle": ".test.0"
    }
  },
  {
    "category": {
      "name": "test2222",
      "val": "test222222",
      "blocktitle": ".test.0.test2"
    }
  }
]
```

My desired output is

```
[
  {
    "category": {
       "name_val" : [
              {
                     "name": "test1111",
                     "val": "test111111111"
              }, 
              { 
                     "name": "test1111111",
                     "val": "test11111111111",
              }
       ]
    },
    "blocktitle": ".test.0"
  },
  {
    "category": {
        "name_val" : [
                  {
                         "name": "test22",
                         "val": "test2222"
                  }, 
                  { 
                         "name": "test2222",
                         "val": "test222222",
                  }
        ]
    },
    "blocktitle": ".test.0.test2"
  }
]
```

I have tried reduce / map / filter but not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Just so it is explicitly stated, how are you wanting to "match"?  Because the names that you have grouped are not equal.  Or is it that you are matching on the blocktitle?

Comment: _“I have tried reduce / map / filter”_ — Great! Show your attempt in your question! We also won’t know what you’re doing wrong, unless you include your attempt and a clear problem statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use ES6 `Array.prototype.reduce` and `Array.prototype.filter` methods:

```
let result = data.reduce((acc, d) => { 
  const found = acc.find(a => a.blocktitle === d.category.blocktitle);
  const value = { name: d.category.name, val: d.category.val };
  if(found) {
    found.category.name_val.push(value);
  }
  else {
    acc.push({blocktitle: d.category.blocktitle, category: { name_val: [value]} });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
```

Where `data` is your initial data array.

Comment: This answer is not performant because you are making a search for all elements in the array with the code `acc.find(a => a.blocktitle === d.category.blocktitle)`..

Comment: @YosvelQuintero Maybe your `a.findIndex(e => e.blocktitle === blocktitle)` is more performant? ;)

Comment: he findIndex() method returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise -1 is returned.
- But, notice that I only do `Array.prototype.findIndex()` if `objHash[blocktitle]` evaluate `falsey`

Comment: @YosvelQuintero Yes, and the same is true also for `find`. Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find): The find() method returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned.

Comment: But you are doing `Array.prototype.find()` for every elements in the `Array.prototype.reduce()`
- And that is not performant ;)

Comment: @YosvelQuintero So, that's true. Maybe if there was a requirement of highest performance, your try might be more appropriate on large data arrays (this also should be investigated, you know, all that temporary memory allocations...). But in terms of readability (let's say, support performance) , I think, there is no doubt that this approach is better.

Comment: Thank you for your dedication and research, however I personally will think always first in **Performance** :D

Answer (score 3):

```js
var test = [
  {
    "category": {
      "name": "test1111",
      "val": "test111111111",
      "blocktitle": ".test.0"
    }
  },
  {
    "category": {
      "name": "test22",
      "val": "test2222",
      "blocktitle": ".test.0.test2"
    }
  },
  {
    "category": {
      "name": "test1111111",
      "val": "test11111111111",
      "blocktitle": ".test.0"
    }
  },
  {
    "category": {
      "name": "test2222",
      "val": "test222222",
      "blocktitle": ".test.0.test2"
    }
  }
];

//create a map of blocktitle to elements with that blocktitle
var temp = test.reduce(function(collection, element){
  if (collection[element.category.blocktitle] === undefined) collection[element.category.blocktitle] = [];
  
  collection[element.category.blocktitle].push(element);
  return collection;
}, {});

//convert temp to expected result
var result = Object.keys(temp).map(function(blocktitle){
  return {
    blocktitle: blocktitle,
    category: {
      name_val: temp[blocktitle].map(function(element){
        return { name: element.category.name, val: element.category.val };
      })
    }
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object as reference to the same group.

```js
var data = [{ category: { name: "test1111", val: "test111111111", blocktitle: ".test.0" } }, { category: { name: "test22", val: "test2222", blocktitle: ".test.0.test2" } }, { category: { name: "test1111111", val: "test11111111111", blocktitle: ".test.0" } }, { category: { name: "test2222", val: "test222222", blocktitle: ".test.0.test2" } }],
    hash = Object.create(null),
    grouped = [];

data.forEach(function (o) {
    var key = o.category.blocktitle;
    if (!hash[key]) {
        hash[key] = [];
        grouped.push({ category: { name_val: hash[key], blocktitle: o.category.blocktitle } });
    }
    hash[key].push({ name: o.category.name, val: o.category.val });
});

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const data = [{category: {name: 'test1111',val: 'test111111111',blocktitle: '.test.0'}},{category: { name: 'test22', val: 'test2222', blocktitle: '.test.0.test2' }},{category: {name: 'test1111111',val: 'test11111111111',blocktitle: '.test.0'}},{category: {name: 'test2222',val: 'test222222',blocktitle: '.test.0.test2'}}]
const result = data.reduce((a, c) => {
  let blocktitle = c.category.blocktitle;
  let objNameVal = { name: c.category.name, val: c.category.val };

  if (a.hash[blocktitle]) {
    let index = a.array.findIndex(e => e.blocktitle === blocktitle);
    a.array[index].category.name_val.push(objNameVal);
  } else {
    a.hash[blocktitle] = true;
    a.array.push({ category: { name_val: [objNameVal] }, blocktitle: blocktitle });
  }
  return a;
}, { array: [], hash: {} });

// Clean hash..
delete result.hash;

console.log(result.array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a reduce to index the items by blocktitle, and then map that object to an array.

```js
function convert(input) {
  const byBlocktitle = input.reduce((byBlocktitleOut, inputObject) => {
    const blocktitle = inputObject.category.blocktitle;

    byBlocktitleOut[blocktitle] = byBlocktitleOut[blocktitle] || [];
    byBlocktitleOut[blocktitle].push(inputObject);

    return byBlocktitleOut;
  }, {});

  return Object.keys(byBlocktitle).map((blocktitle) => {
    const inputObjects = byBlocktitle[blocktitle];

    return {
      category: {
        name_val: inputObjects.map((inputObject) => {
          return {
            name: inputObject.category.name,
            val: inputObject.category.val,
          };
        }),
      },
      blocktitle: blocktitle,
    };
  });
}
```

Working example/test: http://jsbin.com/yifapacupi/edit?js,console,output